# Getting 404 on product page

Tags: laravel, voyager

When trying to access my product page, it returns a 404.

Route

```
Route::get('/used-equipment/{product}.php', 'UsedController@show')->name('product.show');
```

UsedController

```
 * @param string $slug
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $products = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('products')->with('products', $products);
    }
```

Link Path

```
<li><a href="{{ route('product.show', $category->slug) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
```

I know I am probably missing something and I have searched but I just cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have .php in your route? `..nt/{product}.php'`

Comment: So the url is "/category/slug-name.php" (product name)

Comment: Does it work without `.php`?

Comment: No, I tried it with and without.

Comment: Can you change `firstOrFail()` to a `get()` temporarily? Does it return the product then?

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` and show us the result for that route

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ He'll have a web route listing for `/used-equipment/{product}.php` .. I think `firstOrFail` is failing because the product under that slug is missing..

Comment: @WebbieWorks do you get anything when you use get? Also, `.php` is really not necessary.

Comment: I don' t think model not found exeption will result in 404 status, should be status 500 instead @user3532758

Comment: When using get() Undefined variable: product (View: /Users/Home/Desktop/ValiantVoyager2/resources/views/products.blade.php)

Comment: Can you `dd($products)` before calling view?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, yes it will return a model not found but if it's not caught manually, it will be a 404, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Have a look here under `prepareException`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php  Model not found returns a `NotFoundHttpException`.

Comment: I took out anything that had {{$product->something}} and now the page works. With the $product, I get this error - Undefined variable: product (View: /Users/Home/Desktop/ValiantVoyager2/resources/views/products.blade.php).

Comment: You are passing `products` to the view. In the view you are referring to `product`. product should be inside a foreach of `products` since we changed it to a `get`. Important question is did it return a product?

Comment: I am using  @foreach ($products as $product) {{ $product->name }}, (which works on the home page}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202979/discussion-between-webbieworks-and-user3532758).

Answer (score 0):

Use Model on below namespace

```
App\Product;
```

Comment: Not sure what this should help in this case. Did you read the question?